# Banner block (referenced by url) not displayed when using language extensions

Tags: blocks, i18n-l10n, nodes

I have a Banner View block that appears on pages using a reference url field.

When the url: `thispage` is entered in the reference field of the banner, it appears on `domain.com/thispage`.

Now that i enabled 2 other languages en + de this reference is not working. Entering the url with the language extension (`en/thispage`) neither.

I looked into the Views Block. Maybe some code needs to be added. The block has this code under Visibility settings:

```
<?php $nids=arg(1); $datas=node_load($nids); if ( $datas->type=='referenced' ) { return false; } else{ return true; } ?>
```

In the View under contextual filter there is some global php. This might be changed to match the path from other languages (de/thispage)

This is the code from Views:

```
$match_path = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
```

$match_path=explode("/",$match_path);
$match_path=explode("?",$match_path[0]);
return $match_path[0];
//return $_GET['q'];

Any suggestions about how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your configuration at `Configuration -> Languages -> detection and selection`: the order specified there could be what explains the current behaviour in your site.

You'd have to experiment a bit with what the exact order in your case should be. In my experience, I often get these kind of issues to work by using an order like 'URL, Default, User', and not something like 'Default, URL, User'. So try to experiment a bit with the various combinations in this order to see if it helps.